# Verificar valores de un df contra un diccionario

Tags: python, pandas, diccionarios

necesito verificar todos los valores de cada columna de un df respecto de un diccionario con los valores patrones

```
import pandas as pd

df_verificar = {'name':['A','B','C'],'col1':['7','20','300'],'col2':['1','80','nan'],'col3': ['50','62','20']}
df_verificar= pd.DataFrame(df_verificar)

dic_patron = {'A':{'col1':'10','col2':'15','col3':'50'},'B':{'col1':'20','col2':'80','col3':'62'},
          'C':{'col1':'30','col2':'100','col3':'nan'}}
```

Como primer resultado necesitaría ver cuales están ok/fail,  según el Key del diccionario, ejemplo:

```
     name    col1     col2    col3
0     A       Fail    Fail    OK
1     B        OK     OK      OK
2     C       Fail    Fail    Fail
```

y luego filtrar solo los Fail para generar un nuevo DF con los  valores corregidos.
Me podrían indicar sobre que función/librería podría utilizar?
Intente algo con df = df.apply(funcion, axis=1) pero tengo que ir iterando sobre cada nombre  de columna, y en mi caso real son mas de 20 columnas.

```
    def funcion(fila):
     if fila.name == dic_patron.keys():
            if fila.col1 == dic_patron[fila.name ]['col1']:
                return
            if fila.col2 == dic_patron[fila.name ]['col2']:
                return
            if fila.col3 == dic_patron[fila.name ]['col3']:
               return
```

df = df_verificar.apply(funcion, axis=1)

desde ya muchas gracias.. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema algo complicado. El método `apply` sirve para muchas cosas, solo hay que jugar con el resultado. `apply()` nos devuelve una *Serie* de pandas, por lo que podemos usar sus atributos para saber cual es el nombre de su columna (`.name`) y cual es su índice (`.index`). Con estas 2 pequeñas cosas ya tenemos casi todo, solo nos haría falta un ciclo `for` para recorrer los valores y verificarlos.

Empecemos creando una función, la cual recibirá una *Serie* de pandas la cual será las columnas, es decir, por cada iteración recibiremos una columna de nuestro *DataFrame*. A aquella columna le sacaremos su nombre, esto por que en el diccionario las claves tienen el nombre de las columnas y necesitamos acceder a sus valores para comprobarlos. También obtendremos el índice, para luego hacer una relación entre el índice y la columna `name`

```
def validar(valor):
    valores = [] #aquí guardaremos el resultado
    indexs = valor.index #obtenemos los indices
    names = df_verificar.name #sacamos los valores de la columna name
```

la variable `names` es independiente de la columna que recibimos como parámetro, pues aquí estamos obteniendo todos los valores de la columna `name`, para este caso serían `["A","B","C"]`. La variable `indexs` contiene los índices de las filas de la columna recibida, por ejemplo `[0,1,2]`

Si nosotros queremos obtener la letra que corresponde a la primera fila solo hacemos `names[0]`, por lo que podemos acceder al *nombre* de acuerdo al índice de nuestra fila.

- Primera fila (`0`) => Letra "A"
- Segunda fila (`1`) => Letra "B"
- Tercera fila (`2`) => Letra "C"

Con eso obtenemos la letra que nos servirá para ingresar al diccionario, ahora solo faltaría indicar la columna, que hayamos con el atributo `.name` de la columna recibida y comparamos el valor de la fila con el del diccionario y colocamos un `Ok` si coinciden, de lo contrario `Fail`

Nuestra función quedaría así:

```py
def validar(valor):
    valores = [] #aquí guardaremos el resultado
    indexs = valor.index #obtenemos los indices => [0,1,2]
    names = df_verificar.name #sacamos los valores de la columna name => [A,B,C]

    for i in indexs: #Iteramos en los indices
        val = "Ok" if dic_patron[names[i]][valor.name] ==  valor[i] else "Fail"
        valores.append(val)
```

Con `names[i]` estamos accediendo a la letra, luego con `valor.name` accedemos al nombre de la columna y con `valor[i]` accedemos al valor de una fila. Recordemos que la variable `valor` es una columna, por lo que se ve algo así:

```
0      7
1     20
2    300
```

Al indicar `valor[0]` accedemos al primer elemento, en este caso `7` y así con cualquier otro valor.

Lo mismo pasa con la variable `names` que se así:

```
0      A
1      B
2      C
```

Y con `names[i]` accedemos a una de sus posiciones.

Luego simplemente usamos la sintaxis de un operador ternario para dar el valor de `Ok` en caso se cumpla la condición, de lo contrario se usa el valor `Fail` y ese valore es agregado a la lista de `valores`. La sintaxis de un operador ternario es:

```py
<valor_verdadero> if <condición> else <valor_falso>
```

Finalmente solo nos queda retornar la lista `valores` pero no podemos hacerlo así, ya que es una lista y pandas no *interpretará* eso como un *DataFrame* por lo que lo convertimos a una Serie para que pandas pueda reemplazar los valores con facilidad

Ahora solo nos queda hacer

```py
df_verificar.loc[:, "col1":] = df_verificar.loc[:, "col1":].apply(lambda x: validar(x))
print(df_verificar)
```

Donde decimos que las columnas desde `col1` hasta el final serán reemplazadas por el resultado de *aplicarle* una función a las columnas `[col1, col2, col3]`.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda  @Christian me sirvió